# qemu-system_x86-64 can you add a physical hard disk to a virtual machine without being root

Tags: virtual-machines, hard-drive, kvm-virtualization, root, qemu

As it is on the title I want to add a physical partition to my VM without having root privilege. Is it possible from Linux and how should I do this by using only qemu-system_x86-64 ??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Disks on Linux are *usually* (may be distro dependent) owned by the group "disk" and user root. The disks are usually set read/write by the group. So if your root user adds you to the group disk, you should be able to do it.

Unfortunately, if they do that, your user will have read/write on *all* disks, so it's probably not acceptable if you don't already have root access.

Comment: It is possible to set up udev so it will make another group-owner for the node of concrete device. So the proper answer is "yes, but tricky".

Answer (score -2):

You can use `-hda /dev/disk/by-id/xxxxxxx` to attach the Windows physical drive.

Comment: You can get the partition's id by running `ls -al /dev/disk/by-id`